# Flutter/Firebase problem with logout after email user verification

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

i'am building an app with flutter and firebase..(I'am new in flutter development). What I did is a system where the user can signup and signin. Once the user signup an email verification is sent to the user email account. I'll try to put all the step below

1. signup
2. redirect to email verification widget..(this check if user has verified the email with a Timer) if yes, navigator push new Page (HomePage).

the main logic is this one.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
// This widget is the root of your application.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    title: "My App Name",
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: AuthService().handleAuth(),
    theme: ThemeData(
      visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity
    ),
  );
 }}
```

this is what the `AuthService().handleAuth()` does:

```
handleAuth() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
          print(snapshot.hasData);
          if (snapshot.hasData && emailVerificationNeeded() == false) {
            return HomePage();
          }
          return LoginPage();
        } else {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

The verifyPage check with a timer if user has verified the email

```
Future<void> checkEmailVerified() async {
    user = auth.currentUser!;
    await user.reload();
    if (user.emailVerified) {
      timer.cancel();

      Navigator.of(context)
          .pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
    }
  }
```

Until here everything work fine! Now for a test purpose in the HomePage there is a button that fire the following action

`FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();`

if I click in the button and I logout the user still remain in the home page instead of going back to the LoginPage. This problem happen only the first time when the user is redirected in the Verification page. On all the other case if I'm verified and I'm logged in, once I click on the Logout button the user is redirect back to the Login page.

Any ideas?

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

The `StreamBuilder` isn't reacting to changes because you've navigated to another route.

You can use `FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges` instead of `FirebaseAuth.instance.authChanges` as `authChanges` only "notifies about changes to the user's sign-in state (such as sign-in or sign-out)." while `userChanges` listens to different states such as sign-in, sign-out, different user & token refresh.

And then you can call `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.reload();` when you verify the user which removes the need to navigate to the `HomePage` manually.

So when you call `FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut`, it automatically signs you out.

**Code Changes:**

Update `handleAuth` to this:

```dart
handleAuth() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges(),
      ...
    );
}
```

Update `checkEmailVerified` to this:

```dart
Future<void> checkEmailVerified() async {
    user = auth.currentUser!;
    await user.reload();
    if (user.emailVerified) {
      timer.cancel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer... I've done the changes on the code and now it work. The problem now is that whenever I change some data inside the user structure the userChanges is fired and the app go to the HomePage even if I don't  want this. 

So think about a user setting page where I can update firstname and lastname. when I store this information and I cal user.reload() instead of stay on the setting page I will be redirect to the HomePage...what you think about that?